# How to read character by character in text file line using C#

Tags: c#, character

I'm new to C#, so sorry if you find my question stupid.

What I need to do is read a line in text file and show the in

```
Console.WriteLine().
```

So far, I tried this code, but it did nothing but show the counting of characters...

What I'm looking for is to show each character, then step forward to the next, and so forth....

Here is my code:

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    StreamReader MyStreamReader = new StreamReader(path);

    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    {
        int char = MyStreamReader.Read();
        Console.WriteLine(char);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    MyStreamReader.Close();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to read the file character by character, or line by line? Your title says one thing, the body of your question says another. You then present code that wouldn't compile, because `char` is a keyword... (It's also not clear what you mean by "but show the counting of characters number")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                    char Ch = (char)MyStreamReader.Read();
                Console.WriteLine(rc);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
        Console.Write((char)sr.Read());
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't *exactly* know what you're trying to do, but a definite mistake of yours is that your interpreting the characters you read as integers, while you want them as chars. So you should exchange

```
int char = MyStreamReader.Read();
```

with

```
char c = (char) MyStreamReader.Read();
```

And use `c` instead of `char` in the following line:

```
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

If you need further help, please clarify your question.

Comment: @EsckhoBlackshot this is a totally different question.